# Getting those records that have a match of all records in another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Within the realm of this problem I have 3 entities:

1. `User`
2. `Position`
3. `License`

Then I have two relational (many-to-many) tables:

1. `PositionLicense` - this one connects `Position` with `License` ie. which licenses are required for a particular position
2. `UserLicense` - this one connects `User` with `License` ie. which licenses a particular user has. But with an additional complexity: user licenses have validity date range (`ValidFrom` and `ValidTo`)

### The problem

These are input variables:

- `UserID` that identifiers a particular `User`
- `RangeFrom` defines the lower date range limit
- `RangeTo` defines the upper date range limit

**What I need to get**? For a particular user (and date range) I need to get a list of positions that this particular user can work at. The problem is that user must have at least all licenses required by every matching position.

I'm having huge problems writing a SQL query to get this list.

If at all possible I would like to do this using a single SQL query (can have additional CTEs of course). If you can convince me that doing it in several queries would be more efficient I'm willing to listen in.

### Some workable data

Copy and runs this script. 3 users, 3 positions, 6 licenses. Mark and John should have a match but not Jane.

```
create table [User] (
    UserID int identity not null
        primary key,
    Name nvarchar(100) not null
)
go

create table Position (
    PositionID int identity not null
        primary key,
    Name nvarchar(100) not null
)
go

create table License (
    LicenseID int identity not null
        primary key,
    Name nvarchar(100) not null
)
go

create table UserLicense (
    UserID int not null
        references [User](UserID),
    LicenseID int not null
        references License(LicenseID),
    ValidFrom date not null,
    ValidTo date not null,
    check (ValidFrom < ValidTo),
    primary key (UserID, LicenseID)
)
go

create table PositionLicense (
    PositionID int not null
        references Position(PositionID),
    LicenseID int not null
        references License(LicenseID),
    primary key (PositionID, LicenseID)
)
go

insert [User] (Name) values ('Mark the mechanic');
insert [User] (Name) values ('John the pilot');
insert [User] (Name) values ('Jane only has arts PhD but not medical.');

insert Position (Name) values ('Mechanic');
insert Position (Name) values ('Pilot');
insert Position (Name) values ('Doctor');

insert License (Name) values ('Mecha');
insert License (Name) values ('Flying');
insert License (Name) values ('Medicine');
insert License (Name) values ('PhD');
insert License (Name) values ('Phycho');
insert License (Name) values ('Arts');

insert PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID) values (1, 1);
insert PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID) values (2, 2);
insert PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID) values (2, 5);
insert PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID) values (3, 3);
insert PositionLicense (PositionID, LicenseID) values (3, 4);

insert UserLicense (UserID, LicenseID, ValidFrom, ValidTo) values (1, 1, '20110101', '20120101');
insert UserLicense (UserID, LicenseID, ValidFrom, ValidTo) values (2, 2, '20110101', '20120101');
insert UserLicense (UserID, LicenseID, ValidFrom, ValidTo) values (2, 5, '20110101', '20120101');
insert UserLicense (UserID, LicenseID, ValidFrom, ValidTo) values (3, 4, '20110101', '20120101');
insert UserLicense (UserID, LicenseID, ValidFrom, ValidTo) values (3, 6, '20110101', '20120101');
```

### Resulting solution

I've [setup my resulting solution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1214/getting-user-licensed-positions-within-a-particular-date-range) based on accepted answer which provides the most simplified solution to this problem. If you'd like to play with the query just hit *edit/clone* (whether you're logged in or not). What can be changed:

- three variables:

  1. two variable to set date range (`@From` and `@To`)
  2. user ID (`@User`)
- you can toggle commented code in the first CTE to switch code between fully overlapping user licenses or partially overlapping ones.

Comment: With respect to the date ranges, does the given license have to be valid during *any portion* of the RangeFrom/RangeTo, or must it be valid across the *entire range*?

Comment: @Thomas: licenses should be valid in portion (for listing purposes) because I have to display all positions. But other part of the process (not part of this question will require validity across the entire range. If you provide both solutions I'd be even happier.

Comment: Done. My first solution is for anything valid in the range. My second is for anything valid across the entire range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes a number of assumptions (ignores presence of time in the datetime columns, assumes fairly obvious primary keys) and skips the joins to pull in user name, position details, and the like. (And you implied that the user had to hold all the licenses for the full period specified, right?)

```
SELECT pl.PositionId
 from PositionLicense pl
  left outer join (--  All licenses user has for the entirety (sp?) of the specified date range
                   select LicenseId
                    from UserLicense
                    where UserId = @UserId
                     and @RangeFrom <= ValidFrom
                     and @RangeTo >= ValidTo) li
   on li.LicenseId = pl.LicenseId
 group by pl.PositionId 
 --  Where all licenses required by position are held by user
 having count(pl.LicenseId) = count(li.LicenseId)
```

No data so I can't debug or test it, but this or something very close to it should do the trick.

Comment: I've added a simplified script to generate data. As you can see time is not part of validity range. It's just date.

Comment: This seems to actually work for the requirement that user license validity should be defined for the whole range. And it's rather fast as well.

Comment: If "for a single date" rather than "for a range of dates", the two "and" clauses in the subquery can be replaced with `and @TargetDate between ValidFrom and ValidTo`

Comment: @Philip: No not a single date, but when the request range is wider than license range. So license range covers a subset of day in the whole range. Actually 'ValidFrom < @RangeTo and ValidTo > @RangeFrom'. This would cover it as well I suppose.

Comment: @Philip: If you're interested, you can see my end solution using CTEs: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1214/getting-user-licensed-positions-within-a-particular-date-range Thanks for your solution that led to my solution. My app solution is even more complicated and includes even more tables, but your solution led to solution.

Comment: Yes, queries involving time ranges always get more complex than you think they'll be. Thus, my "assumptions" and "lack of testing" in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Runnable Version Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/97595/)

```
WITH PositionRequirements AS (
    SELECT p.PositionID, COUNT(*) AS LicenseCt
    FROM #Position AS p
    INNER JOIN #PositionLicense AS posl
        ON posl.PositionID = p.PositionID
    GROUP BY p.PositionID
)
,Satisfied AS (
    SELECT u.UserID, posl.PositionID, COUNT(*) AS LicenseCt
    FROM #User AS u
    INNER JOIN #UserLicense AS perl
        ON perl.UserID = u.UserID
        -- AND @Date BETWEEN perl.ValidFrom AND perl.ValidTo
        AND '20110101' BETWEEN perl.ValidFrom AND perl.ValidTo
    INNER JOIN #PositionLicense AS posl
        ON posl.LicenseID = perl.LicenseID
    -- WHERE u.UserID = @UserID -- Not strictly necessary, we can go over all people
    GROUP BY u.UserID, posl.PositionID
)
SELECT PositionRequirements.PositionID, Satisfied.UserID
FROM PositionRequirements
INNER JOIN Satisfied
    ON Satisfied.PositionID = PositionRequirements.PositionID
    AND PositionRequirements.LicenseCt = Satisfied.LicenseCt
```

You could probably turn this into an inline table-valued function parameterized on effective date.

Comment: Both CTEs don't need to join `License` table, because `LicenseID` is available via related table. And BTW you're mixing table aliases a bit

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Sure - assuming you have referential integrity, in which case it will be optimized out anyway.

Comment: But it's still not working, since your group by includes both columns. Although this is going in the correct direction. Let me provide you with some data so you will be able to work with it.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik Fixed - brain trying to go in two ways at once.

Comment: @WOW! This Data Explorer is a nice thing alike JSFiddle! Should remember to use it myself as well. Best way to explore SQL problems. Thanks for this. +1 for that.

Comment: @Cade Roux: Check my resulting solution at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1214/getting-user-licensed-positions-within-a-particular-date-range

Answer (score 3):

```
Select ...
From User As U
    Cross Join Position As P
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From PositionLicense As PL1
                    Join UserLicense As UL1
                        On UL1.LicenseId = PL1.LicenseId
                            And UL1.ValidFrom <= @RangeTo
                            And UL1.ValidTo >= @RangeFrom
                Where PL1.PositionId = P.Id
                    And UL1.UserId = U.Id
                Except
                Select 1
                From PositionLicense As PL2
                    Left Join UserLicense As UL2
                        On UL2.LicenseId = PL2.LicenseId
                            And UL2.ValidFrom <= @RangeTo
                            And UL2.ValidTo >= @RangeFrom
                            And UL2.UserId = U.Id
                Where PL2.PositionId = P.Id
                    And UL2.UserId Is Null
                )
```

If the requirement is that you want users and positions that are valid across the entire range, that is trickier:

```
With Calendar As 
    (
    Select @RangeFrom As [Date]
    Union All
    Select DateAdd(d, 1, [Date])
    From Calendar
    Where [Date] <= @RangeTo
    )
Select ...
From User As U
    Cross Join Position As P
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From UserLicense As UL1
                    Join PositionLicense As PL1
                        On PL1.LicenseId = UL1.LicenseId
                Where UL1.UserId = U.Id
                    And PL1.PositionId = P.Id
                    And UL1.ValidFrom <= @RangeTo
                    And UL1.ValidTo >= @RangeFrom
                Except
                Select 1
                From Calendar As C1
                    Cross Join User As U1
                    Cross Join PositionLicense As PL1
                Where U1.Id = U.Id
                    And PL1.PositionId = P.Id
                    And Not Exists  (
                                    Select 1
                                    From UserLicense As UL2
                                    Where UL2.LicenseId = PL1.LicenseId
                                        And UL1.UserId = U1.Id
                                        And C1.Date Between UL2.ValidFrom And UL2.ValidTo
                                    )
                )
Option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

Comment: @Thomas: For the entire range actually @Phillip's solution is very simple and works. I can't spot any bugs in it.

Comment: @Thomas: But this `except` I didn't know it existed. Great stuff man. I can see myself simplifying some queries with it.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Philip's solution will work only if there exists a license that overlaps the range. Suppose our target range is 2011-01-01 to 2011-12-31. Now suppose that a given user has two licenses matching a given position: license 1: 2000-01-01 to 2011-03-31, license #2: 2011-12-01 to 2012-01-31. For the given user and position, there does exist a license that overlaps the range. However, there also exists days in our target range over which the user does not have a license and, given the second condition, should be rejected.

Comment: @Thomas: Philip's solution is actually very simple and works for both conditions (full and partial date range overlap) with minor change in where clause.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Actually, as I look closer, Phillip's solution will return a false positive only where a given user has a single license that overlaps the target range (vs two in my previous example). Thus, if the target range is Jan-Dec of 2011 and the user's license expires in Mar-2011, it will still show as a valid position because it was valid for a portion of the target range.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Btw, for the first condition of your OP (i.e. that a valid license exist in the range), Philip's solution works just fine. You only run into a complication if you want to force the license to be valid for all days in the range.

Comment: @Thomas: That is true, but that can be easily solved by changing the where clause in `where` clause to ones that you've written in your case(es). I haven't noticed that when rewriting his query because I've actually set correct conditions in my query. I'll still reward you +1 because of the extensive effort you've put into this. But I'l staying with a simplified variation on Philip's answer.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - WRT to the problem of ensuring that license is valid across the entire range, adding a simple Where clause will not do it. You need to ensure there does not exist a date in the target range over which a given user's license does not overlap which is why I used the Calendar table.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Btw, another scenario to test is one where for a given user and position, the user has two license both which overlap the range. I.e., target range = All of 2011, position X has one required license. Suppose a given user has two applicable licenses with the following validity dates: Jan-Jun 30 and July 1 to Dec 31. Philip's solution will return that the user has two license over the given range and that does not equal the one license required.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not sure I understand which overlapping you have in mind that would cause problems? But you can check my resulting solution based on @Philip's solution. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1214/getting-user-licensed-positions-within-a-particular-date-range Hit **edit/clone** (depending whether you're logged in or not). The first CTE has both versions of where clause. Toggle commenting both and see how it works (and change date range (variables) to see how it works). I think it works as expected.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - One curiosity in the design that I see is in the UserLicense table. You are not allowing for a scenario where a user has the same license over two different periods. I.e., a given user cannot have a given license for May-June and also for Aug-Sept. Each user can have a reference to a given license at most once.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - continued, allowing a user to only reference a given license once is fine if you do not have to provide for knowing whether the user *was* licensed over a given period or on a given day. Whenever a license is renewed, you simply update the existing row instead of creating a new row with a non-overlapping date range. This restriction is key. With this constraint, the scenario I presented with respect to a given user have multiple licenses be valid during the target range cannot happen and therefore Philip's solution (or mine) would return the correct result.

Comment: @Rober Koritnik - Here's a modified version of your query using Philip's solution. Notice the change in the UserLicense table which allows for multiple UserId-LicenseId values over different date ranges (preventing overlap is yet another question). Notice that Mechanic no longer shows because the given user has two licenses in the target range which does not match the one required license for a mechanic. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/97703/getting-user-licensed-positions-within-a-particular-date-range

Comment: @Thomas: In real life my `UserLicense` table defines a create+update trigger that prevents overlapping definitions of the same license. And even though they would overlap I'm using distinct in `UserLic` CTE result set so in the partially overlapping license range with my desired date range gives me only one record per license.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Is your actual scenario akin to the UserLicense table structure in my example where user can have multiple rows for the same license over non-overlapping ranges? Unless your trigger also forces the ranges to be contiguous, you will still get holes. E.g. 2011-01-01 to 2011-12-31. For user 1 and license 1, imagine the following date ranges: 2011-01-01 to 2011-03-31 and 2011-05-01 to 2011-12-31. Even using distinct, your query would not pick up that the user did not have a needed license for a portion of the target range.

Comment: @Thomas: trigger only prevents from overlapping same licenses but doesn't prevent holes. And my scenario of getting the appropriate positions is strictly based on all positions that may be ok for any given day and not all. Displaying positions based on date range would require a more complex process that would become user unfriendly hence I'm avoiding it.